# Spark Cloudera - Worker Memory Setting

Tags: memory, apache-spark, cloudera, worker

Im new in Spark and I've recently install CDH with Spark standalone version.

Im using single cluster test in my laptop for my spark, everything is fine but my worker's memory, 512.0 MB, instead of 8 GB like my laptop RAM.

[image: Spark Web UI Picture]

Anyone can help me with this setting issue?

Comment: Is It a solution for a job - That the column Memory per Node in my pic? My problem is the master only see the worker as a maximum 512 MB memory Worker.

Comment: There are worker and executor nodes. The link in the answer below provides many settings you can change to utilize more memory.